# Azure Function stopped working - Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.BlobTriggerAttribute'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

My always running function stopped working recently. So I started to look what's changed, loaded solution locally in VS2017 and hit compile. Everything seems to be compiling but when I run it locally I get:

> > Error indexing method 'CheckNewBlob.Run'
> >     Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'CheckNewBlob.Run'. System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.BlobTriggerAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

ok, I tried to register the binding and tried to install latest Azure.WebJobs.Core (whatever it's called) package - no luck! It just does NOT compile anymore! I even tried to recreate the project and that was waste of time. Not the function is broken.
And haven't even gotten to Table storage output...

So, Azure functions team, what should we do with all that?

Suffice to say the existing function is not triggered anymore by new blobs. It used to work just yesterday, but that's it, not anymore.

Azure Functions Core Tools (2.0.1-beta.36)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12050.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129 has everything you need to know (and email was sent earlier about it to all subscription owners). See also https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3363.

Quoting for your particular error:

> You'll get this if you're using Azure Storage based functionality (blob/queue/tables trigger/input/output) and you haven't installed the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage extension.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. It's just not in the docs so it was confusing... Or did I just miss it?

Comment: Right now we're focusing on the transition document. For new apps, you would not see this as the template would have the right references to begin with

Comment: can you please tell me more explicitely what was the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `Platform` from `32 Bit` to `64 Bit` fixed this issue for me.[image]